# Why create a new Object - Java Tetris Tutorial

Tags: java, object, tetris

Im just new to Java and I found this good tutorial for creating a Java Tetris Game.

I dont have a mentor or a tutor to help me with this - Ive been looking for one for ages :(
so currently im self learning Java and PHP :)

Anyways heres the website I found: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/tetris/

One method of the program I dont get in the `Shape.java` class:

```
public Shape rotateLeft() 
{
 if (pieceShape == Tetrominoes.SquareShape)
     return this;

 Shape result = new Shape();
 result.pieceShape = pieceShape;

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
     result.setX(i, y(i));
     result.setY(i, -x(i));
 }
 return result;
}
```

Why do we need to create a new Object `Shape result = new Shape();` if can already get the current piece from the `pieceShape` variable?

Comment: where is pieceShape declaration? maybe it is used is some other part of the code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the naming is a bit misleading in this tutorial. The class called `Shape` represents a single item that falls down. The `Tetrominoes` `enum` seems to be describing **which kind** of item it is (i.e. it's "shape"!).

So the code you posted creates a new **item** and specifies its shape.

The `rotateRight()` and `rotateLeft()` methods don't modify the shape itself to allow the `tryMove()` method to check if the move is legal and ignore it if it isn't (for example if you'd rotate an item into the wall). `tryMove()` simply keeps the old values (including the old `Shape` instance) when the move is not allowed. If `rotateLeft()`/`rotateRight()` modified the `Shape` then it would have to undo that operation, which would complicate the code.

Also, there are a few nitpicks with this code:

- I'd call the `Tetrominoes` class `Tetromino`, as `enum` types are usually named in the singular (since you often reference a *single* element: `Tetromino.SquareShape`.
- I'd add the information about the concrete coordinate of each `Tetromino` into that `enum`, effectively putting much of the logic from the `setShape()` method into it.
- The `Board` class mixes the logic and the presentation, it should be separated (makes it much easier to test).

  For example the `Board` class could implement all the logic without any of the graphics (i.e. don't reference anything from `java.awt` or `javax.swing`). Then you'd write a `BoardPanel` that draws the state of the `Board` and interacts with the user, calling the appropriate `Board` methods.

Comment: Thanks Heaps!!! i didnt expect to get an answer this quick!!! This explains a lot! thank you thank you thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The method you've posted returns a shape that is rotated left. If you didn't create a new Shape, the original shape, which is a field of the class and used everywhere else, would have been rotated.

In the case of the square shape, which isn't changed when rotated left, you can still return the original one.

Comment: Thank you kgiannakakis, your answer was simple and direct to the point - why cant i check 2 accepted answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Without looking thoroughly at the tutorial I'd say this: Since `Shape` seems to represent an individual item and `rotateLeft()` might be a instance method of `Shape` it might also be ok to rotate the item in place, i.e. not to return a rotated copy but change the block' coordinates of the current shape. Creating a new item to fall down would then mean to create a new `Shape` with default orientation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the author doesn't mutate the `Shape` in `rotateLeft()` because it might not be accepted as a valid move. In `Board` the inner `TAdapter` class calls `tryMove()` and only sets the current `Shape` (variable `curShape`) if it's acceptable. If it were mutated prior to that check it'd have to set it back when invalid. The method should perhaps be named `rotatedLeftCopy()` to indicate that it's not changing the state. Or the check should be performed beforehand and then `rotateLeft()` would be safe to change the `Shape` in place.

Comment: mutate? im not pro yet - i guess ill learn that mutate technique in the near future. I still must thank you for your answer :)

Comment: By mutate I simply mean that it's changing the state of the object. So setting the X and Y variables in this case. There are advantages to writing immutable objects (`String` for instance is immutable) whereby you can't change the state. Instead you'll find methods (like `split()`) that return a copy of the object with the changes you wanted. It's also sometimes a defensive programming technique to return a copy of an object so that users don't accidentally manipulate the contents outside of the control of the class that returned it.